# Order By on Join takes ages

Tags: mysql, sql

When I add an ORDER BY derived from a JOINED table, the time to execute the query goes up from 0.008 seconds to 0.50 seconds, this although there's an index on the order by field. The following is the query:

```
SELECT a.productid 
FROM   products a 
   JOIN products_lng b FORCE INDEX (primary)
     ON a.productid = b.productid 
        AND b.code = 'US' 
   JOIN pricing c 
     ON c.productid = a.productid 
   JOIN thumbnails d 
     ON d.productid = a.productid 
   JOIN bigthumbnails e 
     ON e.productid = a.productid 
   JOIN products_categories f 
     ON f.productid = a.productid 
WHERE  a.forsale = 'Y' 
GROUP  BY b.productid 
ORDER  BY b.product
```

Explain plan:
[image]

b has the following indexes:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `products_lng` (
 `code` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `product` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `descr` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `full_descr` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `processed` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`code`,`productid`,`product`),
 KEY `ad` (`code`,`productid`,`product`,`descr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: That's because MySQL already used the primary key, it won't use another index for ordering after that.

Comment: When I add in the "PRIMARY" index, the field "product" as well, it only takes more time

Comment: Actually, why are you using table `a`? You don't need it.

Comment: because i left out fields to make it look simpler

Comment: Perhaps a dump of `SHOW CREATE TABLE b` is easier to make sense of.

Comment: done b is btw an alias @Jack Even when i do force index (primary) and add "product" to the primary index and do < group by b.productid, order by b.product > it doesn't improve the speed at all.

Comment: @Jack This query is used as an nested table for other queries (around 2 or 3) when the script is run. Would it maybe improve if I would put it in a temporary table and add an index to "product" and do the sorting at the other queries? I'm a bit afraid though that creating the indexes on the temporary table are even going to take more time...

Comment: You've basically carpet bombed your table with indexes; surely you don't need so many in the first place. And just keep in mind that **only one** key per table is used in the query; if another key needs to be used for ordering it will scan instead.

Comment: @ypercube how is that supposed to help? Even i'm here testing with the simpler version. --:Jack Yes, i've just been playing around, unfortunately without success...

Comment: @hakre i've no idea what you mean or what you're trying to achieve with your (unconstructive) comment. But no, i don't care about points anyway. sorry

Comment: What forced you to create all these indexes on the table?

Comment: @hakre what forced you to ask questions that are not related. If you see the execution plan, they are not used anyway so why bother. I've deleted them now, i hope it makes you happy. Most of them were already there b4 i started this.

Comment: I'll stop answering unconstructive questions now. Anyone who has an answer, please post it as an solution. When I find a way how to decrease the time of the query, i'll post it.

Comment: I was just interested, looking at your table description I've seen many indexes, often covering the same column multiple times. So I wondered, and thought, best would be to ask you directly to get some unfiltered feedback. But it looks like that it's only okay for you to ask questions but not if you are getting asked in context of your question. A bit sad :/

Comment: @hakre You're acting like this is a forum asking silly questions and comments. Stop doing that. If you don't know the answer than just don't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it appeared to be that the combination of ORDER BY and GROUP BY was the reason that the executement of the query took longer than normal. By placing the query however in a sub query and therefore separating the ORDER BY and GROUP BY I managed to drastically limit the execution time to 0.0015 sec instead of the original 0.5 sec. I still have to adjust the query to my requirements but the following is how it should look like. Basically it comes down to that in the subquery you define the WHERE parameters and the surrounding query which values you wish to select.

```
    SELECT z.*,d.*,e.*
FROM products_lng z
JOIN thumbnails d ON d.productid = z.productid
JOIN bigthumbnails e ON e.productid = z.productid
WHERE EXISTS
    ( SELECT b.productid
     FROM products b
     JOIN pricing c ON c.productid = b.productid
     JOIN products_lng i USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON i.productid = b.productid
     AND i.code = 'US'
     JOIN products_categories f ON f.productid = b.productid
     WHERE b.productid = z.productid
     GROUP BY b.productid )
ORDER BY z.product
```